# request_module: runaway loop modprobe binfmt-0000

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, modprobe

I'm running CentOS 7. Everything was working fine, until I had one pending update, which I accepted and rebooted.

Now the system fails to boot and instead reports:

```
request_module: runaway loop modprobe binfmt-0000
request_module: runaway loop modprobe binfmt-0000
```

I've attempted to research this extensively using Google, and this error has been reported over a decade ago, but there is no clear solution on how to fix it. Please help! Thanks!